# git mv multiple files, preserve extension

Tags: git, mv

I have about 10 directories, each with contents that match this pattern:

```
x.js
x.d.ts
x.ts
```

and I want to rename these files to:

```
index.js
index.d.ts
index.ts
```

is there a `mv` or `git mv` command that I can use to rename the files?

something like:

```
git mv --match x.* index.*
```

I am not really sure.

Comment: WIthout git, use `rename 's/x\./index./' x.*`

Comment: I guess it might be best to go with a cp command instead of mv, in case I mess something up lol